# Why does Java StandardCharsets provide three "UTF-16" encoding types but Notepad only provides 2 options (BE & LE)?

Tags: java, unicode, notepad++, utf-16, notepad

[`StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) provides three entries for [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16):

```
    /**
     * Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, big-endian byte order
     */
    public static final Charset UTF_16BE = new sun.nio.cs.UTF_16BE();
    /**
     * Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, little-endian byte order
     */
    public static final Charset UTF_16LE = new sun.nio.cs.UTF_16LE();
    /**
     * Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, byte order identified by an
     * optional byte-order mark
     */
    public static final Charset UTF_16 = new sun.nio.cs.UTF_16();
```

Notepad (& Notepad++) Provides following:

[image]

Why is UTF-16 missing in Notepad? (Is UTF-16 and UTF-16 BE same thing?)

Comment: I don't use notepad or notepad++, but are those options for decoding/reading/opening the text file, or is it for encoding/writing/saving the file?

Comment: In Notepad, While Saving ; and in Notepad++, while displaying file can check encoding options

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 1):

These are documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#standard):

> - When decoding, the UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE charsets interpret the initial byte-order marks as a ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE; when
>   encoding, they do not write byte-order marks.
> - When decoding, the UTF-16 charset interprets the byte-order mark at the beginning of the input stream to indicate the byte-order of the
>   stream but defaults to big-endian if there is no byte-order mark; when
>   encoding, it uses big-endian byte order and writes a big-endian
>   byte-order mark.

So in short, `UTF_16BE` and `UTF_16LE` do not care about BOM, and so does not correspond to the "UTF-16 BE BOM" or "UTF-16 LE BOM" options in notepad++ as you seem to imply.

On the other hand, `UTF_16` does write a BE BOM when encoding, so would correspond to choosing the "(Convert to) UTF-16 BE BOM" option in notepad++. Note that for decoding, the BOM is "optional".

As for the NotePad options, they do not say whether they include a BOM, so I'm not sure if they do. If they do not, then it would be equivalent to `UTF_16BE` and `UTF_16LE`'s encoding behaviour.

As for *why* notepad++ does not have the equivalent of the `UTF_16BE` and `UTF_16LE` options, or why Java doesn't have a "UTF-16 LE BOM" option, it is not really a useful question to ask. [As Eric Lippert said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585),

> **features are not magically implemented by default and then the implementations have to get removed by the development team for a good reason.** Rather, all features are unimplemented by default and have to be **thought of, designed, specified, implemented, tested, approved and shipped to customers.** All that costs time and effort.

Comment: For anyone that wants to see the inclusion or omission of the BOM, here is a bit of example code: `Files.writeString( Paths.get( "/Users/whatever/bogus_UTF_8.txt" ) , "UTF_8" , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ); 
Files.writeString( Paths.get( "/Users/whatever/bogus_UTF_16.txt" ) , "UTF_16" , StandardCharsets.UTF_16 ); 
Files.writeString( Paths.get( "/Users/whatever/bogus_UTF_16BE.txt" ) , "UTF_16BE" , StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE ); 
Files.writeString( Paths.get( "/Users/whatever/bogus_UTF_16LE.txt" ) , "UTF_16LE" , StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE );`